# Accessing this value from a website using the selenium library in python

Tags: python, selenium

I was able to use selenium to create a driver, and use it to login to this site and load this page

[image]

How should I go about trying to access this 2.8 ± 0.5 value? I was able to access the `<iframe>` by using

```
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_all_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')))
```

but then when I did

```
iframe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'src')))
```

I couldn't get anything.

Is there any workaround for how to get this value? Should I try to go to the src link first? Is selenium the correct library to attempt this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the `<iframe>` before locating elements under it. You can use `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` for that

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')))
```

You can also use the `id` or `name` attributes without `By`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('MLVALUEDFT_dielectric_total'))
```

And now use `driver.find_element(...)` to locate the element.

To switch back out of the `<iframe>` use `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: I tried doing that, and my value for iframe became the boolean `True`.

Comment: @S2H Did you call it inside `until`?

Comment: I copied and pasted the first line exactly.

Comment: @S2H Edited my answer. You need to switch and than use `driver.find_element`.

Comment: I ran the first line of your edited answer and it came back as the boolean True. Then I ran `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'src')` and got a `NoSuchElementException` Error

Comment: @S2H well you don't have any element with class `src` within the iframe. You can try using the `text_small` class if its unique or the text to the left of the value you want.